# Why won't my figure show updated plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a init function that renders a matplot figure:

```
    self.fig = plt.figure()
    self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.line_1, = self.ax.plot([], [], 'r-')
    g = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.ui)
```

I have another function in the same class that should update the graph with new points:

```
count = 0
def update(self, data):
        self.count +=1
        self.line_1.set_ydata(data)
        self.line_1.set_xdata(self.count)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
```

Although an empty graph shows, when I call the update function elsewhere (where data is a float value such as 0.643), nothing happens at all.

I want to achieve this with as much simplicity as possible - as you can probably tell! Cheers.

Comment: as for me you should set some list in `set_xdata(some_list)`. Now you use single number and it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the xdata to a single number, which is probably not what you want. You could try instead

```
self.line_1.set_xdata(range(len(data)))
```

assuming you want the given list `data` to be plotted against their indices.

Another problem is that the axes limits aren't updated, so probably your data will not be in sight. You can fix this by calling `ax.relim()` and `ax.autoscale_view()` between updating the data and redrawing:

```
    def update(self, data):
        self.line_1.set_ydata(data)
        self.line_1.set_xdata(range(len(data)))
        self.ax.relim()
        self.ax.autoscale_view()
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
```

In fact, it seems based on your use of `count` and your comment about data being a float value, that you want to use this method to add a single value at a time. When you call `line_1.set_ydata()`, you are not appending a value—you are replacing the whole ydata with the given value, as the name implies!  To append a value, do something like this:

```
    def append(self, val):
        ydata = self.line_1.get_ydata()
        ydata = np.append(ydata, val)
        self.line_1.set_ydata(ydata)
        self.line_1.set_xdata(range(len(ydata)))
        self.ax.relim()
        self.ax.autoscale_view()
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
```

(Assuming you have `import numpy as np` beforehand.)

Comment: Looks great  - will get back to you shortly.

Comment: you are a hero. Thank you.